# playframework fall back configuration?

Tags: scala, playframework

How to let playframework's configuration falls back to other configuration files if a default one is not exist.

For example, by default play use application.conf, if it does not exist, use c1.conf. if c1.conf does not exist, uses c2.conf.

I use play framework 2.3 in scala

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand why this would be desirable? I guess it is to do with having specific configuration files for different environments - It feels dangerous to work with fallbacks like this because it could easily end up in difficult to track down issues due to misconfigurations. It feels like specificity is best. Maybe you have a different use case in mind

Comment: See the answer of Daniel Olszewski - Play tries to read alternative config (if specified) - and if it doesn't exists it always falls back to `application.conf`, so default config should always be present, and only if you need to override it, then use alt file.

Comment: @MikeCurry the reason I need this is that I want to run unit test in separate configuration file however not all members in my team want this. So using this fallback, play will use unit test configuration file if it is exist otherwise it uses default configuration file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a feature doesn't exist in the Play framework. All you can do is to specify which file should be used as the configuration by passing one of the possible properties to your startup script.

Available parameters are described in the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ProductionConfiguration) under the section called `Specifying alternative configuration file`.

- **-Dconfig.resource** - allows you to choice a file within your application
- **-Dconfig.file** - sets a file from outside of your application
- **-Dconfig.url** - uses a file loaded from the given URL

If none of this properties is passed to the application, it'll use **application.conf** as a default one.

To complete your task, you can write a bash script which will verify whether the script that you want to run exists. If so, pass it using one of aforementioned parameters or use a different one otherwise.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is the best thing I can do for now.